# Is there anything wrong with my code?

Tags: objective-c

```
-(void)processGlyph:(int)glyphOne withGlyph:(int)glyphTwo
{
    answer = glyphOne + glyphTwo;
    NSString *tempText = [[NSString alloc] init];
    tempText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",answer];
    [self dispatchText:tempText];
    [tempText release];
}

-(void)checkReadyToProcess
{
    if (count >= 2) {
        [self processGlyph:firstGlyph withGlyph:secondGlyph];
    }
}

-(void)dispatchText:(NSString *) theText
{
    answerText.text = theText;
}
```

Comment: No, it works exactly as you described it should.

Comment: quitting unexpectedly, giving me a exc_bad_access signal and im almost positive it has to do with some part of this code.

Comment: @austin i was simply asking if my syntax was correct

Comment: @Joe: syntax errors won't trigger EXC_BAD_ACCESS signals, they'll just not compile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  It is here:

```
NSString *tempText = [[NSString alloc] init];//leaked
tempText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",answer];//creates new autoreleased object
...
[tempText release]; //causes an eventual crash
```

You are allocating an `NSString`, replacing the variable with an autoreleased `NSString`, and then releasing the autoreleased `NSString`.  This will lead to a memory leak (from the original `NSString`) and a crash from over-releasing.

Instead, just do:

```
NSString *tempText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",answer];
```

You don't have to release it.

Comment: +1 Gonna give you my vote because I answered this doubtfully and deleted my answer, while you wrote yours knowing what exactly is happening.